# Curl of rotational fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vortex

If I consider a fluid which rotates as a rigid body, then the curl of the velocity field is $2\vec\omega$ where $\vec\omega$ is the angular velocity of the rigid body, but let us assume that we are considering a fluid which does not rotate like a rigid body. According to my book, $\nabla\times\vec{v} = 2\vec\omega$ is still valid, but for each point taken individually. Each point, according to the book, can be seen as a rigid body. The point is that the book does not tell if $\vec\omega$ is the angular velocity of the generic element of fluid around itself or not.

Comment: The [vorticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorticity) of a fluid (which may encompass a rigid body) is *defined* as $\vec{\omega}\equiv\nabla\times\vec v\,.$ For the rigid body vorticity coincides with twice its spin angular velocity. In general, vorticity and angular velocity are different concepts even though the notation may suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a 2D, steady velocity field $V(u(x,y),v(x,y))$ where $u$ and $v$ are the x- and y-components of the velocity of a particle at point $(x,y)$.

Imagine a square $ABCD$ of fluid with dimensions $\delta x \times \delta y$ with its edges at coordinates $A=(x,y), B=(x+\delta x, y), C=(x+\delta x, y+\delta y), D=(x, y+\delta y)$. Perhaps imagine the fluid in this square being dyed red. As time evolves, in a general velocity field, so will the geometry of the square of selected fluid.

For angular motion, we will be interested in angles through which the sides of the square rotate. When are the angles nonzero? For rotation of side $\overline{AB}$ the condition is $\partial v /\partial x \neq 0$ and for the rotation of $\overline{AD}$, the condition is $\partial u / \partial y \neq 0$. To see this, let time $\delta t$ go by. After $\delta t$, if the above conditions are satisfied, the particle at position $(x + \delta x, y)$ will have moved through an angle $\delta\theta \approx (\partial v / \partial x)\cdot \delta x \delta t / \delta x$. Then of course $\omega$ about the $\overline{AB}$ axis would be nonzero. A similar formula for change in angle holds for $\overline{AD}$ axis.

The rate of rotation about $\overline{AB}$ need not be the same as $\overline{AD}$. Generally, it is not. So we can't, unlike with rigid-body rotation, simply say one of them defines $\vec{\omega}$. So instead, we take the average.

This average is the definition of $\vec{\omega}$, in general fluid flow..

Comment: Can you explain better what you said? Anyways rot v = 2ω